# Migrating Files from Bower to Lib folder in ASP.Net Core Web

Tags: asp.net, typescript, npm, gulp, bower

I am new to ASP.Net Core + NPM.  I have been following various online examples, and while their screen shots show it working, most don't actually work (in-full)...and [**the one I am working with now**](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/how-setup-angular-2-typescript-project-visual-studio-2017.html) isn't "quite" working as advertised either.

For some reason, Bower Packages are NOT auto-migrating into the `wwwroot\lib` folder. Normally, I would expect them to do so by-default...but that may be asking to much.

**Q:** How do I get the **Bower Packages** to auto-install into the **'Lib'** directory?

- Also, just in case, I checked and created an EMPTY VERSION of the Web Application & it doesn't migrate the **Bower Packages** either.  So I guess the expectation is for us to do it by-hand.

[image]

HERE ARE THE STEPS I HAVE TAKEN:
Using: Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition)

**STEP 1:** 
Created the following project, added MVC folders & folders into WWWRoot (see image below)

- ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project
- Added MVC Folders
- Added WWWRoot Folders
- Added folders for TypeScript files

**STEP 2:** 
Configure TypeScript

- tsconfig.json, the TypeScript compiler configuration file (see below)
- typings, the TypeScript type definition files file (see below)

TSCONFIG.JSON

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "rootDir": "App",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": ".",
    "debug": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

TYPINGS.JSON

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine"
  }
}
```

**STEP 3:** 
Configure NPM to bring-in Angular 2 and its dependencies

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "NO404 administration panel",
  "name": "no404 backoffice",
  "readme": "no404 backoffice",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",

    "bower": "1.7.9",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": ">=3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": ">=2.5.2",
    "gulp-copy": ">=0.0.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": ">=0.1.7",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": ">=1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": ">=0.2.0",
    "gulp-tsc": ">=1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": ">=1.2.0",
    "gulp-watch": ">=4.3.9",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run watch\" \"npm run tsc:w\"",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "ngc": "ngc"
  }
}
```

**STEP 4:** 
Configure Gulp

GULP.CONFIG.JS

```
module.exports = function () {

    var base = {
        webroot: "./wwwroot/",
        node_modules: "./node_modules/"
    };

    var config = {
        /**
         * Files paths
         */
        angular: base.node_modules + "@angular/**/*.js",
        app: "App/**/*.*",
        appDest: base.webroot + "app",
        js: base.webroot + "js/*.js",
        jsDest: base.webroot + 'js',
        css: base.webroot + "css/*.css",
        cssDest: base.webroot + 'css',
        lib: base.webroot + "lib/",
        node_modules: base.node_modules,
        angularWebApi: base.node_modules + "angular2-in-memory-web-api/*.js",
        corejs: base.node_modules + "core-js/client/shim*.js",
        zonejs: base.node_modules + "zone.js/dist/zone*.js",
        reflectjs: base.node_modules + "reflect-metadata/Reflect*.js",
        systemjs: base.node_modules + "systemjs/dist/*.js",
        rxjs: base.node_modules + "rxjs/**/*.js",
        jasminejs: base.node_modules + "jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/*.*"
    };

    return config;
};
```

**STEP 5:** 
Create Gulp tasks

GULPFILE.JS

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    //return $.rimraf('wwwroot/js/*.min.js', cb);
    return gulp.src('wwwroot/js/*.min.js', { read: false }).pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    //return $.rimraf('wwwroot/css/*.min.css', cb);
    return gulp.src('wwwroot/css/*.min.css', { read: false }).pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('minify:css', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.css)
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.cssDest));
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);
gulp.task('minify', ['minify:css']);

gulp.task("copy:angular", function () {

    return gulp.src(config.angular,
        { base: config.node_modules + "@angular/" })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib + "@angular/"));
});

gulp.task("copy:angularWebApi", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.angularWebApi,
        { base: config.node_modules })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("copy:corejs", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.corejs,
        { base: config.node_modules })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("copy:zonejs", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.zonejs,
        { base: config.node_modules })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("copy:reflectjs", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.reflectjs,
        { base: config.node_modules })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("copy:systemjs", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.systemjs,
        { base: config.node_modules })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("copy:rxjs", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.rxjs,
        { base: config.node_modules })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("copy:app", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.appDest));
});

gulp.task("copy:jasmine", function () {
    return gulp.src(config.jasminejs,
        { base: config.node_modules + "jasmine-core/lib" })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.lib));
});

gulp.task("dependencies", [
    "copy:angular",
    "copy:angularWebApi",
    "copy:corejs",
    "copy:zonejs",
    "copy:reflectjs",
    "copy:systemjs",
    "copy:rxjs",
    "copy:jasmine",
    "copy:app"
]);

gulp.task("watch", function () {
    return $.watch(config.app)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.appDest));
});

gulp.task("default", ["clean", 'minify', "dependencies"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

For bower, a configuration file named `.bowerrc` determines the destination of installed packages. Make sure this file contains:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Now once you call `bower install` in the command line, the packages should be restored in `./wwwroot/lib` relative to where your bower file is.

Just to make sure, npm is different than bower. They are 2 different package managers so bower packages need to be specified in `bower.json` (which you don't have as your screenshot shows). For npm, packages are specified in `package.json`

In your steps, you are using npm. Your gulp task should work fine and move packages from `./node_modules/` to `./wwwroot/lib/`. However, recent versions of npm do not allow blank spaces in `description` and `name` fields in the `package.json` file. You should update those then try and run the following:

```
npm install
npm update
gulp
```

Comment: THANK YOU: Where should I put bower.bowerrc?  At root?

Comment: You need 2 files. `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` both should be in root. `bower.json` should include the packages you want. Check here for how to use it: https://github.com/bower/spec

Comment: But I think you should use npm anyway, there are many packages that you won't find in the bower registry. Many of the angular ones aren't there.